# Prove the following inequality with one integral and one sum

Tags: integration, inequality, summation

Let $f(x)$ be a derivable function on the interval $(0,1)$ and continuous on $[0,1]$. 
Assume that $|f'(x)| \leq M$ for every $x \in (a,b)$. 
Prove the following inequality for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$,
$$
  \left| \int_0^1 f(x) dx - \frac{1}{n} \sum_{k=1}^n f(k/n) \right| \leq \frac{M}{n}.
$$

Answer (score 0):

$$\left|\int_{\frac {k-1} n}^{\frac  k n} [f(x)-f(\frac k n )] dx\right|\leq \int_{\frac {k-1} n}^{\frac  k n} M\left|x-\frac k n\right| dx $$ by MVT. Since $\left|x-\frac k n\right|\leq \frac  1n$ this gives $$\left|\int_{\frac {k-1} n}^{\frac  k n} [f(x)-f(\frac k n )] dx\right|\leq \int_{\frac {k-1} n}^{\frac  k n} M \frac 1 n dx=\frac M {n^{2}} $$ Sum this over all $k$. Can you finish the proof now?

Comment: in some steps I don't understand where the absolute value ends

Comment: @Nexus99 I hope it makes sense now.